# I cant download expo client

Tags: react-native, expo

For the last 24 hours I have been trying to get my expo client to build JavaScript on my device. I have been using expo for some weeks now.  And thou it may be difficult to get it running I some how manage to use it for some hours. Usually I can easily connect using tunnel.  Recently I was able to 'trick it' to work without internet. But for the last 24 hours I can't get to work using any of the options available... I have scout the Internet for solutions and tried them with no success .
I keep getting type error  `java.net sockettimeoutexception network timeout error .....1000ms` I have had to reset a lot on my system disabled all firewalls. Pause antivirus , reset react native packager hostname, clear cache for both expo and npm etc..
Lastly I tried removing and downloading the expo client app . But the app fails to download. Tried other apps and they work OK..

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it to install after rebooting several times